# Localizing a text field containing a number in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am currently working on a project to internationalize one of our ruby-on-rails web applications so that it can be used in other countries (France will be the first one in this case).

A particular issue I haven't worked out yet is with the displaying of numeric fields. When displaying numbers for display purposes only, I do the following:

```
<%= number_to_percentage(tax.rate, :precision => 2)%>
```

In English, this shows **17.50**, but in French it shows **17,50** (with a comma in place of the decimal point) which is as expected. The problem comes in the Edit form, when I show a text field

```
<%= f.text_field :rate, :size => 15 %>
```

When this renders a text box on the screen, the text box always shows **17.50** with a full stop rather than a comma for French. I am not sure that is correct.

When I tried doing the following:

```
<%= f.text_field :rate, :size => 15, :value => number_with_precision(f.object.rate, :precision => 2) %>
```

This did indeed show **17,50** in the text box for French, but when I click on the Update button to save the form, the Ruby validation kicks in and tells me that **17,50** is not a number (or rather it says "n'est pas un nombre"). I have to enter **17.50** to get it to save.

To be honest, I am not entirely sure on the correct thing to do here. Should all countries enter numbers with full stops in text boxes, or is there a way to get Ruby-on-Rails to display commas, and validate them appropriately?

Comment: I'd simply use a gsub before validation to have the value formatted properly.

Comment: I'm a bit of a Ruby Dunce at the moment, and so don't actually know what a gsub is at the moment....

Comment: for the search/replace you are doing, do a Global Substitution (gsub) as opposed to just the first match you find

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## TL;DR

This is the kind of things I hate to do over and over again (I'm serving french users, they're easily confused with dots as the decimal separator).

I exclusively use the [delocalize gem](https://github.com/clemens/delocalize) now, which does the format translation automatically for you. You just have to install the gem and leave your forms as-is, everything should be taken care of for you.

## I like to read, give me the long explanation

The basic conversion is quite simple, you have to convert back and forth between the following formats:

- The backend one, which is usually English, used by your persistent storage (SQL database, NoSQL store, YAML, flat text file, whatever struck your fancy, ...).
- The frontend one, which is whatever format your user prefers. I'm going to use French here to stick to the question<sup>*</sup>.

<sub>* also because I'm quite partial towards it ;-)</sub>

This means that you have two points where you need to do a conversion:

1. **Outbound**: when outputting your HTML, you will need to convert from English to French.
2. **Inbound**: When processing the result of the form POST, you will need to convert back from French to English.

### The manual way

Let's say I have the following model, with the `rate` field as a decimal number with a precision of 2 (eg. `19.60`):

```
class Tax < ActiveRecord::Base
  # the attr_accessor isn't really necessary here, I just want to show that there's a database field
  attr_accessor :rate
end
```

The **outbound** conversion step (English => French) can be done by overriding `text_field_tag`:

```
ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  alias original_text_field_tag text_field_tag
  def text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
    value = options.delete(:value) if options.key?(:value)
    if value.is_a?(Numeric)
      value = number_with_delimiter(value) # this method uses the current locale to format our value
    end
    original_text_field_tag(name, value, options)
  end
end
```

The **inbound** conversion step (French => English) will be handled in the model. We will override the `rate` attribute writer to replace every French separator with the English one:

```
class Tax < ActiveRecord::Base
  def rate=(rate)
    write_attribute(:rate, rate.gsub(I18n.t('number.format.separator'), '.')
  end
end
```

This look nice because there's only one attribute in the example and one type of data to parse, but imagine having to do this for every number, date or time field in your model. That's not my idea of fun.

This also is a naïve<sup>*</sup> way of doing the conversions, it does not handle:

- Dates
- Times
- Delimiters (eg. `100,000.84`)

<sub>* did I already tell you I like French?</sub>

### Enter delocalize

[Delocalize](https://github.com/clemens/delocalize) is working on the same principle I outlined above, but does the job much more comprehensively:

- It handles `Date`, `Time`, `DateTime` and numbers.
- You don't have to do anything, just install the gem. It checks your ActiveRecord columns to determine if it's a type that needs conversion and does it automatically.
- The number conversions are pretty straightforward, but the date ones are really interesting. When parsing the result of a form, it will try the date formats defined in your locale file in descending order and should be able to understand a date formatted like this: `15 janvier 2012`.
- Every outbound conversion will be done automatically.
- It's tested.
- It's active.

One caveat though: it doesn't handle client-side validations. If you're using them, you will have to figure out how to use i18n in your favourite JavaScript framework.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go, and if it indeed does the trick, I will accept your answer. It is rather annoying that Ruby On Rails does not do this out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

This is the gsub technique :

In your model :

```
before_validation :prepare_number


def prepare_number
  self.rate.gsub(/,/, '.') if self.rate.match /,\S/
end
```

Comment: I think there's a need to handle "." also in numbers so gsub technique won't be always effective. For ex: How about this number  "2.100,00" this is actually equivalent to "2,100.00" in  ? gsub will result in "2.100.00"