# Rails Amounts in Thousands (Without Commas) Are Truncated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I previously had this question:
[Rails Amounts in Thousands Are Truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949749/rails-amounts-in-thousands-are-truncated)

However, I've run into the issue again with numbers that are greater than 1000, but don't have a comma.

So, for example, when "1590" is read in from a JSON response, my DB stores `1.00` in the DB for `reg_price`.

```
[
  {
    "reg_price": "1590"
  }
]
```

Schema

```
 create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.decimal  "reg_price",                           precision: 10, scale: 2
 end
```

Model

```
response = open_url(url_string).to_s
products = JSON.parse(response)

products.each do |product|
  product = Product.new(
    reg_price: item['reg_price'].gsub(',', ''),
  )
  product.save
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: I follow storing currency value at lowest measurement unit, like paisa or cents. While presenting the required format is handled via money gem

Comment: `reg_price: item['reg_price'].gsub(',', '')`  There is something wrong here. Where did `item` come from?

Comment: Does `Product.new(reg_price: "1590").save` result in a DB value of `1.00`?